# Active Record Nested Map

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Flatten doesn't work because it returns an array.

I want to collect all the desks inside all the offices inside all of the organizations inside an event.

desks = Event.FOO.scheduled_organizations.FOO.offices.FOO.desks

I tried using a where clause to make sure I only grabbed organizations which were scheduled but I still got back 1 array. I need to recursively flatten. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it in several steps? Each step will give you the ids to search on the next one. I don't think you can't do it the way you want natively. Maybe using something like squeel.

Comment: Active record will probably generate a single query (with some subqueries). I really can't say if this is fast or not compared with a single one with like three joins. But it worth try and measure.

Comment: Is there seriously no way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

so Event -> scheduled_organizations -> offices -> desks

As long as you specify your tree as "throughs" on Event like below:

```
has_many :scheduled_organizations
has_many :offices, through: scheduled_organizations
has_many :desks, through: :offices
```

If that can't work in this case for you, you can use

```
desks = @event.scheduled_organizations.map(&:offices).map(&:desks)
```

Comment: undefined method .map for Event -- map only works on collections yeah?

Comment: @quantumpotato totally correct. Updated to match. (I originally had `Event.all.etc`

Comment: Undefined method on collection proxy  : https://gist.github.com/quantumpotato/726a2547a902c78dbe8c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062155/why-am-i-getting-this-undefined-method-activerecordassociationscollectio advises using "first" but that doesn't let me map them